# Spring Boot Content Type Error even when specified in Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-data

I have an issue in Spring Boot with Kotlin

I have a function that accepts all major Content Types  as defined below:

```
@PostMapping(
        value = ["/users/new"],
        consumes = [
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE]
    )
    fun registerNewUser(
        @RequestHeader("X-Forward-For") ipAddress: String?,
        newUser: NewUser,
        request: HttpServletRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> {
        var realIPAddress = ipAddress
        if (realIPAddress == null) {
            realIPAddress = request.remoteAddr
        }
        return userService.registerUser(realIPAddress!!, newUser)
    }
```

Here is how my NewUser class is defined in kotlin

```
data class NewUser(val email: String?, val password: String?)
```

Here is how I am doing the check in the registration function

```
if (!StringUtils.hasText(newUser.email)) {
            return responseHandler.errorResponse(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Please provide an email address"
            )
        }
```

Now when I sent a post request with postman and even axios I keep getting the error as shown in the screenshot below
[image]

That error message should only be displayed if email address is not provided. But as you can see clearly, the email address is provided in the JSON Payload.

What could be wrong?

Note: This works when the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but doesn't work when the Content-Type is `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

put `@RequestBody` before newUser parameter to specify that input should be inside http body part. by default function parameters in spring are considered to be url parameters which can be further clarified with `@RequestParam`.

there are 2 ways to insert request parameters into http request. one is to attach request parameters to end of the url and the other is to put in http body with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content-type.